# Physics/Math conversion

Tags: physics, unit-of-measure

I'm having difficulties solving this conversion. I know what to do at first but the way to set this up is a bit confusing:

[image]

Comment: You're asking to convert 60 ft/s to yrds/day, yes?

Comment: Neat fact: you can do these conversions in the [google search bar](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=60%20ft%2Fs%20in%20yards%2Fday#q=60+ft%2Fs+in+yards%2Fday)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom heck, why even bother learning anything?

Comment: I mean, it's a good way to check answers.  There's a reason it's a comment

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert $60 ft/sec$ to yards per day?

Well, a good way to think of these types of conversions is to treat your units as an $"x"$ in your equation. As in, if $1 yd = 3 ft$, then $\frac{1 yd}{3ft} = 1$, and if you were to multiply this by another equation, you are essentially multiplying it by 1, and thus making no difference.

So, you have $60$ feet per second, and you want to in effect "cancel" out the feet and the seconds and replace them with yards and days, so you want a relationship between how many seconds are in a day and how many feet are in a yard.

We have $60$ seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour and $24$ hours in a day, so $60*60*24 = 86,400$ seconds in one day. For feet to yards, you know that $3$ feet $=$ $1$ yard. So, using all of these conversions, set it up as so:

$$\frac{60 ft}{1 sec} * \frac{86,400 sec}{1 day} * \frac{1 yd}{3 ft}$$

Using regular rules of fractions, cancel the units as if they are variables and you'll see that the unit that is left is yards per day. The only thing is, this is not $20$ yards per day, so I have no idea how you got that...